# Generic event class - am I over-complicating it?

Tags: c++, optimization, c++11, event-handling

I'd like some advice about any better or cleaner way to implement this class, if there's any.

I made it using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204578/is-it-possible-to-implement-events-in-c/5204594#5204594), posted on Stack Overflow, as reference. A lot of problems arose when I switched C function pointers to `std::function` due to the lack of the equality operator on it, so I ended up implementing a internal class to hold a pointer to the function and make it comparable.

```
#include <list>       // std::list
#include <algorithm>  // std::find
#include <functional> // std::function
#include <memory>     // std::auto_ptr

template<typename FuncTemplate>
class Event
{
public: // Type declarations
    class Delegate;

public:
    Event() = default;
    ~Event() = default;

    Event& operator+=(const Delegate& func)
    {
        events.push_back(func);
        return *this;
    }

    /**
     * Removes the first occurence of the given delegate from the call queue.
     */
    Event& operator-=(const Delegate& func)
    {
        auto index = std::find(events.begin(), events.end(), func);
        if(index != events.end() )
        {
            events.erase(index);
        }

        return *this;
    }

    /**
     * Fires this event.
     *
     * @param args Arguments to be passed to the called functions. Must have the exact same
     * number of arguments as the given event template.
     */
    template<typename... Args>
    void operator()(Args... args)
    {
        for (typename std::list<Delegate>::iterator i = events.begin(); i != events.end(); ++i)
        {
            (*i)(args...);
        }
    }

private: // Private variables
    std::list<Delegate> events;

public:
    class Delegate
    {
    private: // Type declarations
        typedef std::function<FuncTemplate> Func;

    public:
        Delegate (const Func& func) : functionPtr(new Func(func))
        {
            /* NOP */
        }

        inline bool operator== (const Delegate& other) const
        {
            return (functionPtr.get() == other.functionPtr.get() );
        }

        template<typename... Args>
        void operator()(Args... args)
        {
            (*functionPtr)(args...);
        }

    private:
        std::shared_ptr<Func> functionPtr;
    };
};
```

This is the code I used to test it:

```
void prints(const std::string& e)
{
    std::cout << "From prints: " << e << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Event<void(const std::string&)> messageReceived;

    auto printLambda = [](const std::string& e) -> void
    {
        std::cout << "From print lambda: " << e << std::endl;
    };

    Event<void(const std::string&)>::Delegate printDelegate1(printLambda); // Testing lambda
    Event<void(const std::string&)>::Delegate printDelegate2(prints); // Testing standard functions
    Event<void(const std::string&)>::Delegate printDelegate3(printLambda); // Testing lamda on another delegate instance
    Event<void(const std::string&)>::Delegate printDelegate4(printDelegate1); // Testing cloning constructor
    Event<void(const std::string&)>::Delegate printDelegate5 = printDelegate1; // Testing assignation

    std::cout << "Is Delegate 1 = Delegate 1? " << (printDelegate1 == printDelegate1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Is Delegate 1 = Delegate 2? " << (printDelegate1 == printDelegate2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Is Delegate 1 = Delegate 3? " << (printDelegate1 == printDelegate3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Is Delegate 1 = Delegate 4? " << (printDelegate1 == printDelegate4) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Is Delegate 1 = Delegate 5? " << (printDelegate1 == printDelegate5) << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

    messageReceived += printDelegate1;
    messageReceived += printDelegate2;
    messageReceived += printDelegate3;
    messageReceived += printDelegate4;
    messageReceived += printDelegate5;

    messageReceived("This should be printed five times");

    std::cout << std::endl;

    messageReceived -= printDelegate1;
    messageReceived -= printDelegate2;
    messageReceived -= printDelegate3;

    messageReceived("This should be printed two times");

    std::cout << std::endl;

    messageReceived -= printDelegate4;
    messageReceived -= printDelegate5;

    messageReceived("Whoops! Something is wrong");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before looking at the code, and just having a quick read-through, the first thing that sticks out to me are the comments:

```
private: // Private variables

Delegate (const Func& func) : functionPtr(new Func(func))
{
    /* NOP */
}

#include <memory>     // std::auto_ptr
```

The first is obvious, the second is slightly misleading, and the third is completely wrong (I know you meant `std::shared_ptr`, but having an incorrect comment is worse than no comment at all).

Your `operator()` should probably be using perfect forwarding instead of passing a copy of all the arguments. Also, since you're already using lambdas and variadic templates, you might as well take advantage of auto and/or range based for loops:

```
template<typename... Args>
void operator()(Args... args)
{
    for (typename std::list<Delegate>::iterator i = events.begin(); i != events.end(); ++i)
    {
        (*i)(args...);
    }
}
```

I'd change this to:

```
template<typename... Args>
void operator()(Args&&... args)
{
    for (auto i = events.begin(); i != events.end(); ++i)
    {
        (*i)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
}
```

Similarly for the `operator()` in `Delegate`.

Instead of using `new` in:

```
Delegate (const Func& func) : functionPtr(new Func(func))
```

You should prefer `std::make_shared`, as it is potentially slightly more efficient, and good practice to get into, as if you ever use `new` multiple times
before a sequence point, there can be memory leaks if (say) the second `new` throws before the `shared_ptr` is fully constructed.

Comment: I wouldn't have noticed the `std::auto_ptr` comment had you not mentioned it. I use the first comment you mentioned as labels, since the code folding on Sublime 3 doesn't hide them (the _Private_ part is redundant, though). I made the changes you suggested, and I might make a benchmark later to see the differences. Anyway, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @RaphaelC. Honestly, unless you're passing a number of really expensive parameters, you're unlikely to see much of a difference here. It's (potentially) a construction + move (which for a lot of classes is just swapping pointers) instead of a construction + copy construction.

Comment: You can cut down that for loop still with a range-based for.